# Hibernate SerializationException: could not deserialize

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, serialization, crud

This is my Data Base
[Data Base table photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DkV4.png)

When i establish conetion with my Class i specify all column and primary key but when i start my code i get Serialization Exception, in code i am  supose to set LocalDate manualy with HTML form but i get serialization exc and Whitelabel Error Page apeare. Please help

My class

```
package com.developer.SpringMySQL.models;


import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "parkingtable")
public class Car  implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="carID")
    private Integer  carID;
    @Column(name = "culoarea")
    private String culoarea;
    @Column(name="model")
    private String model;
    @Column(name = "combustibil")
    private String combustibil;
    @Column(name = "categoria")
    private String categoria;
    @Column(name = "data_inregistrarii")
    private LocalDate data_inregistrarii;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(String culoarea,
               String model, String combustibil, String categoria,
               LocalDate data_inregistrarii) {
        this.culoarea = culoarea;
        this.model = model;
        this.combustibil = combustibil;
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.data_inregistrarii =data_inregistrarii;
    }

    public void setCombustibil(String combustibil) {
        this.combustibil = combustibil;
    }

    public LocalDate getData_inregistrarii() {
        return data_inregistrarii;
    }

    public void setData_inregistrarii(LocalDate data_inregistrarii) {
        this.data_inregistrarii = data_inregistrarii;
    }

    public Integer getCarID() {
        return carID;
    }

    public void setCarID(Integer carID) {
        this.carID = carID;
    }

    public String getCuloarea() {
        return culoarea;
    }

    public void setCuloarea(String culoarea) {
        this.culoarea = culoarea;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getCombustibil() {
        return combustibil;
    }

    public void setCombustibilul(String combustibil) {
        this.combustibil = combustibil;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }
}
```

And also i create a controler class

```
package com.developer.SpringMySQL.controllers;


import com.developer.SpringMySQL.models.Car;
import com.developer.SpringMySQL.models.CarParkingRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Controller
public class CarParkingController {

    //todo use encapsulation
    @Autowired
    CarParkingRepo carParkingRepo;

    @RequestMapping("/car")
    public ModelAndView doHomeCar() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("parkingTable");
        modelAndView.addObject("lists", carParkingRepo.findAll());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/carSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView doHomeSave(@RequestParam("carID") String carID,
                                   @RequestParam("culoarea") String culoarea,
                                   @RequestParam("model") String model,
                                   @RequestParam("combustibil") String combustibil,
                                   @RequestParam("categoria") String categoria,
                                   @RequestParam("data_inregistrarii") LocalDate data_inregistrarii) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/car");
        Car car;
        if (!carID.isEmpty()) {
            car = carParkingRepo.findOne(Integer.parseInt(carID));
        } else {
            car = new Car();
        }
        car.setCuloarea(culoarea);
        car.setModel(model);
        car.setCombustibilul(combustibil);
        car.setCategoria(categoria);
        car.setData_inregistrarii(data_inregistrarii);
        carParkingRepo.save(car);

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/parkingTableView/{carID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doHomeView(@PathVariable("carID") int id) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("parkingTableView");
        modelAndView.addObject("luckyNumber",100);
        modelAndView.addObject("lists", carParkingRepo.findOne(id));

        return modelAndView;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/deletee/{carID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doHomeDelete(@PathVariable("carID") int id) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/car");

        carParkingRepo.delete(id);

        return modelAndView;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/Edit/{carID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doHomeEdit(@PathVariable("carID") int id) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("parkingtableEdit1");

        modelAndView.addObject("lists", carParkingRepo.findOne(id));

        return modelAndView;
    }





}
```

Heare is Stack trace

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303138
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:862) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:354) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2790) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:329) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.developer.SpringMySQL.controllers.CarParkingController.doHomeCar(CarParkingController.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your LocalDate is not deserialized, so yo need to give it a format,for supporting this POST /carSave?data_inregistrarii=2017-08-04

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/carSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doHomeSave(@RequestParam("carID") String carID,
                               @RequestParam("culoarea") String culoarea,
                               @RequestParam("model") String model,
                               @RequestParam("combustibil") String combustibil,
                               @RequestParam("categoria") String categoria,
                               @RequestParam("data_inregistrarii") 
                               // Add this format
                               @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate data_inregistrarii) { 

  // code here

}
```